# JPF(Java Path finder) for web application

Tags: java, path-finding

Can JPF(Java Path Finder) be used for web applications. I have a web application (struts application). Now how do i test\verify it using JPF. Does a main method is mandatory to run jpf and find the results? because in a Servlet we dont have a main method and how do we approach for this?

Comment: Have you ever written a custom servlet? Seems not. A servlet has a `do` method for every HTTP method.

Comment: My question is if you go to JPF source you can see that it in gov.nasa.jpf.jvm.JVM class they are looking for main class name and arguments, Now a Servlet has many entry points like doGet/doPost/... how do i make my doGet as the entry point. Some sample source will be appreciated.

Comment: By calling your servlet with HTTP GET.

Comment: You mean to say write a main method and call the servlet service method, But the Servlet should run in container right?

Comment: Somewhat. Have you ever done Servlet coding? It does not seem like. You can call any code you like in a `do` method.

Comment: Michael-O: I am a masters graduate and have 4 years of industrial experience in Struts, Springs and other MVC frameworks :) Now my problem is not with Servlets or struts, it is with JPF(Java Path Finder). Have you ever used JPF with web applications? If so please tell me how did you do so, that would suffice.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't, this is just a lib for me. So I don't see a problem using it with Servlets.

Comment: Its not just a lib, JPF is a VM build over JVM. You will come to know the problems once you use it. You need to have better knowledge on JPF to answer. Anyways thanks for your answers.

Comment: Well, this makes it complicated. Maybe you should run in different VMs and use RMI?

Answer (score 1):

You can use JPF's symbolic execution extension to "run" a single method:
http://babelfish.arc.nasa.gov/trac/jpf/wiki/projects/jpf-symbc/doc

Haven't used it myself, though.